# url shows weird string

Tags: asp.net, url, iis-7

I'm testing my asp.net website on my local server (Windows Server 2008, IIS 7.0.6), and when I type in just the IP address in my browser, e.g.,

```
192.168.0.5
```

it comes back like this:

```
http://192.168.0.5/(S(u0nmzwxobbwpuk1mtvuybwn0))/default.aspx
```

The weird stuff between .0.5/ and /default.aspx changes every time I type in the ip and hit enter.

The content shows up correctly, but obviously there's a problem with the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you might be using cookieless sessions.

Basically ASP.NET is storing your session id in the query string instead of storing it in a cookie.  Looks gross, but allows you to use session state when someone does not accept cookies.  You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Guessing here - in your `web.config` file, you have set the `sessionState` `cookieless` attribute to `UseUri` or to `true`.

See the documentation on the [`sessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) element.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you Have Cookieless Sessions enabled. Below article illustrates the behavior:

[MSDN - Cookie Less Sessions in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)

Changing the Setting in Web.Config can change the behavior:

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```